# Showing that the gradient $\nabla f(x)$ is parallel to constraint surface gradient $\nabla g(x)$ at an extreme point on the surface

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Let $f(x)$ a function $f:\mathbb{R}^D \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. $g(x)$ is another $D$ dimensional function. Then we have a constraint equation $g(x)=0$. Now, we have a local, constrained extreme point $x'$ on the constraint surface $g(x)=0$, for which it is, in a close neighborhood, either $f(x') > f(y)$ or $f(x') < f(y)$ where all $y$'s are on the constraint surface as well. ($x'$ is a point which would be the aim of a Lagrange multiplier problem here).

Now, I want to show the following: At $x'$, the gradient $\nabla f(x')$ is perpendicular to all vectors which lie on the tangent plane to the surface $g(x)=0$ at point $x'$; $\nabla f(x')$ and $\nabla g(x')$ are parallel to each other. In other words, for all $\vec{u}$ with $\nabla g(x') . \vec{u}=0$ it is $\nabla f(x'). \vec{u}=0$ when $x'$ is a constrained extreme point on the surface of $g(x)=0$.

Intuitively I know that this is true, which leads to the construction of Lagrange functions. But how can this be shown true, with a rigorous proof?

Comment: Implicit function theorem allows you to move tangent to any direction $\vec{u}$ perpendicular to $\nabla g(x')$ on the surface $g(x)=0$ near $x'$. On the other hand, if $x'$ is a constrained extremal point, then, by the univariate calculus theory of extrema, the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $\vec{u}$ must vanish. This holds for all vectors $\vec{u}\perp\nabla g(x')$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for the answer. I know a bit about the IFT, but how we can utilize it here to show that on $\vec{u}$ the derivative vanishes? Can you elaborate on this a bit more?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Here, we use IFT to convert $f(x)$ to a univariate function which moves on the vector $\vec{u}$ and passes through $x'$ and then show that the derivative is zero at $x'$. Is that right?

Comment: That's the idea. Sorry, no time to elaborate now.